# Can we modify Data when publisher send the data to particular subscriber in TIBCO EMS or RV?

Tags: middleware, tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-rv, tibco-topic

I am using TIBCO ems as middle ware in my project. TIBCO ems[Publisher, Server] publish the topic and according to topic subscribe , publisher send the data to subscribers.When publisher send the data I want to apply my algorithm over that data and then want to send it to subscribers. Is this possible in TIBCO EMS?or If it is possible in TIBCO RV? 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible. Take the data off your subscribe queue, apply your algorithm, and then republish the result to a new queue.

Comment: Please tell me the path of where TIBCO store the queue ?

Comment: well the path depends on the publish queue, right? It can be whatever you have prescribed it to be. For example, something like: (1) publish data to queue: raw_data (2) subscribe to raw_data and pop messages off that queue (3) apply your algorithm (4) publish the result to algo_data (5) tell subscribers to listen to algo_data